# Ajax not working in a conditionally rendered include page in jsf

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf-2

I have a `.xhtml` page with many included other `.xhtml` pages, each one of them is rendered with a certain action

```
<h:form>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <h:commandLink
                onclick="hideWrapper()">
                <f:ajax listener="#{Bean.createListener}" event="action"
                    render=":parent-panel" />
                <div class="test">
                    <div class="icon"></div>
                    <div class="title">#{msgs.create_new_bean}</div>
                    <span>#{msgs.create_your_bean}</span>
                </div>
            </h:commandLink>


            <h:commandLink >
                <f:ajax listener="#{Bean.historyListner}" event="action"
                    render=":parent-panel" />
                <div class="History1">
                    <div class="icon"></div>
                    <div class="title">#{msgs.history}</div>
                    <span>#{msgs.history}</span>
                </div>
            </h:commandLink>
        </div>
    </h:form>

    <h:panelGroup id="parent-panel">
        <c:if test="#{Bean.activeEditFlag}">
            <h:panelGroup id="active-page">
                <ui:include src="active.xhtml" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </c:if>

        <c:if test="#{Bean.createFlag}">
            <h:panelGroup id="create-page">
                <ui:include src="create.xhtml" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </c:if>

        <c:if test="#{Bean.activeEditFlag}">
            <h:panelGroup>
                <ui:include src="edit.xhtml" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </c:if>

        <c:if test="#{Bean.historyFlag}">
            <h:panelGroup id="history-page">
                <ui:include src="history.xhtml" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </c:if>

    </h:panelGroup>
```

Each included page contains components like `h:commandLink` or `h:selectBooleanCheckbox`, there are two pages that must be rendered from the first time `render=true`, those are working fine with the ajax but when it comes to any other page that went from render=false to ture, they are rendered but the components containing ajax are not working. any ideas??

Comment: it seems you have separate `h:form`s in included xhtml files. please give it a try by nesting "parent-panel" in a single form, removing the inner forms from included xhtml files, and executing only the necessary components in `f:ajax` actions. i'm trying to avoid the re-rendering of `h:form`s.

Comment: I think this is the problem too, but it is difficult to remove those forms, any other ideas??

Comment: @tt_emrah what do you mean by re-rending the forms? is the main problem that the form re-render again?

Comment: after the ajax event, you do `render=":parent-panel"` and there are forms nested in "parent-panel". for many times i have seen that rendering an `h:form` after initial page load messes with ajax requests, but i cannot be 100% sure without trying it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

I found two solutions for this problem, but they are more of working around,because as I understood and I quote  "rendering an h:form after initial page load messes with ajax requests", and for my situation I can't remove the h:form from the included pages. So instead of `c:if` I used `f:subview` it has a `render` attribute you can check this at [subview with including pages](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/core/f_subview.html)
The other solution is using javascript to append the pages on the main page

```
  $('.main-button2').click(function(e) {
                    $(".parent-panel").empty();
                    $.get("../history.xhtml", function(data) {
                        $(".parent-panel").append(data);
                    });
                });
```

Comment: i'll ask this out of curiosity: does it work if you use `<h:panelGroup id="active-page" rendered="#{Bean.activeEditFlag}">`, instead of `<c:if test="#{Bean.activeEditFlag}">`?